# Why do some people consider Jeshurun to be an end-times figure?

Tags: israel

I realize that the prevailing interpretation is that Jeshurun is another name for Israel. However some people think that Jeshurun refers to some type of end-times figure. What reason do they have to think that?

> Deu 32:15  But Jeshurun grew fat and kicked. You grew fat, thick, and satisfied. Then he forsook God who made him, and lightly esteemed the Rock of his salvation.

Comment: I don't get the question. The nation of Israel ***is*** an end-times figure... So if Jeshrun is another name for Israel, that makes ***Jeshrun*** an end-times figure. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @DavidStratton that may be the connection he is lacking (I'm unfamiliar with the doctrine here so I'm unable to judge)

Comment: @DavidStratton I misinterpreted the phrase "end times figure" to mean person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nation of Israel is an end-times figure in certain end-times teachings... So if Jeshrun is another name for Israel, that makes Jeshrun an end-times figure.

The short version is as follows:

This is tied to Dispensationalism, and certain premillennial views. The short version is that we are currently living in the "Church Age" which is a brief respite in the Seventy weeks of Daniel. This is a time period here God's dealings with Israel is suspended. In the pre-tribulation rapture view, the Church will be raptured, which will signl the start of the seven year Great Tribulation, in which God will again be dealing directly with Israel. Those seven years represent the final "week" in the seventy weeks of Daniel.

References for further study:

[Why do some people consider Jeshurun to be an end-times figure?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11335/why-do-some-people-consider-jeshurun-to-be-an-end-times-figure)

http://gracethrufaith.com/ikvot-hamashiach/the-70-weeks-of-daniel/

http://www.raptureready.com/rr-pre-trib-rapture.html

*The usual disclaimer, I'm just outlining the beliefs. Not everyone agrees with these views.*